# Suppress PMD VariableNamingConventions rule for lowercase 'log' field

Tags: java, logging, pmd

I'm using the PMD for checking the Java source files. In case of the `log` variable, the PMD shows that the variable should be upper-case, because it is `static` and `final`.

I would like to exclude the `log` variable from this rule. Is this possible?

```
private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplianceImporter.class);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to configure PMD rules to ignore certain XPaths:

```
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/naming.xml/VariableNamingConventions">
    <properties>
      <property name="violationSuppressXPath" value="//VariableDeclaratorId[@Image='log']"/>
    </properties>
  </rule>
```

This cleanly excludes all fields named `log` from `VariableNamingConventions` rule and no code pollution with `//NOPMD` is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add //NOPMD and the end of the line

```
private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplianceImporter.class); //NOPMD
```

Here it's a deep explanation

http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/suppressing.html